# Capturing data when specific cells change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to capture data from specific cells when certain cells change:

When cell B5 changes I want to capture the data in cells B3 and B4 in columns A and B in Sheet2.

I also want to be able to capture data in cells C3 and C4 in columns C and D Sheet2 when cell C5 changes.

The macro does do this - however, when B5 or C5 changes it captures the data from both columns B & C - rather than when B5 changes capturing just data from cells B3 & B4 and when C5 changes just the data from cells C3 & C4.

Any help very much appreciated - this is my code currently:

```
    Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Worksheet_Change Range("B5:C5")
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Capture data when cell B5 changes
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("B3").Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("B4").Value
Application.EnableEvents = True

 End If

'Capture data when cell C5 changes
         If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("C3").Value
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("C4").Value
Application.EnableEvents = True



  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does **B5** contain a *formula* or a *constant* ?

Comment: You could take out the two `Application.EnableEvents` lines in the center of each `IF` block.  No point turning it to `TRUE` just to turn it to `FALSE` on the very next line.

Comment: So when **B5** changes, you want second to last cells in column **A** and **B** to be updated with the values in cells **B3** and **B4** respectively?

Comment: B5 is a formula

Comment: Yes Zac - when B5 or C5 change I am after the second to last cells in column A and B to be updated with the values in cells B3 and B4 (if B5 changes) or C3 and C4 if C5 changes - thanks for looking at this folks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With oWS
        If Not Intersect(Range("B5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("B3").Value
            .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("B4").Value
        ElseIf Not Intersect(Range("C5"), Target) Is Nothing Then
            .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("C3").Value
            .Range("D" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("C4").Value
        End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> When the cell value is changed by a formula

If you want the values to be updated when the cell value is changed by a formula, approach is different:

First, in your `Module`, declare public variables:

```
Public sB5Value As String
Public sC5Value As String
```

Then, in `Workbook_Open` capture the current values for your cells

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        sB5Value = .Range("B5").Value
        aC5Value = .Range("C5").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Now in your `Worksheet` (which I am assuming is **Sheet2**) calculate function you can perform the check

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
       ' B5 change check
       If .Range("B5").Value <> sB5Value Then
           .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("B3").Value
           .Range("B" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("B4").Value

           ' We have to update the value for B5 in the variable
           sB5Value = .Range("B5").Value
       End If

       ' C5 change check
       If .Range("C5").Value <> sC5Value Then
           .Range("C" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("C3").Value
           .Range("D" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = .Range("C4").Value

           ' We have to update the value for C5 in the variable
           sC5Value = .Range("C5").Value
       End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**NOTE:** I've left the original code just incase if it's needed
You can also make the `IF` conditions non case sensitive (i.e. use **LCase** or **UCase**) but I'll leave that to you. I haven't tested this code but the idea should work

Comment: That works great when I update the cells B5 & C5 manually - but these cells are being updated by formula and when C5 changes - it also grabs the data from B3 & B4 (as well as the data I want in C3 & C4)

Comment: Didn't realise that the cell value was being changed by a formula. I've added approach to show how you can update required cells when value is changed by a formula